# Difficulty Accessing Helm-Managed Environment Variables in React Project Served by Nginx via Docker Container

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, nginx

"I've developed a React project that utilizes a Dockerfile to create an image. To serve this React project, I've configured Nginx. I've integrated Helm to manage environment-specific configurations by defining values in `values_dev.yaml` and `values_prod.yaml`. Although I can verify the presence of these added values within the pod, attempting to access them via `process.env.value` within the React app isn't yielding the expected results."

Comment: Have you tried with Docker + environment variable? Do that before you involve Helm and Kubernetes.